# Difference between AysncResult, and callback with error_callback in python pools

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am using Pools to kick off worker processes in python3.6.  The workers will return True or False after completion, and I was wondering what the difference is between using the AsyncResult returned object or using a callback function to check if the worker returned True or False.  From my understanding the callback is called in the main process, the same place I would do the checking anyway.

```
#Using the AsyncResult way
def check_result(result):
  if result:
    #Successful do something
  else:
    #Failed

with Pool() as pool:
  result = pool.apply_async(upload, (args, ))
  check_result(result.get())

#Using callbacks 

def check_result(result):
  if result:
    #Successful do something

def err_result(result):
  #Do something

with Pool() as pool:
  pool.appy_async(upload, (args,), callback=check_result, error_callback=err_result)
```

I see that in python3.6 they allow error_callback, so are these two bits of code equivalent?  What are the pros and cons of both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison between `AsyncResult` and `callback` is somewhat unlucky. 
 Note that you only have callbacks available for asynchronous methods (returning `AsyncResult` objects), so there is no 'versus' in this story regarding these things.

When you write `check_result(result.get())`, you don't pass some `AsyncResult`-object into `check_result`, but an already awaited normal result, in your case a boolean value (if not an exception). So it's not a difference between `AsyncResult` and `callback`, but between manually calling `check_result` on a result or registering a callback beforehand.

> I see that in python3.6 they allow error_callback, so are these two bits of code equivalent? What are the pros and cons of both?

No, these two snippets are not equivalent. `error_callback` is an exception handler, your possible `False`-result won't trigger that, but an exception will.
Your `result` argument within `err_result` will be filled with an exception instance in such a case. The difference with your upper snippet is, that an exception there will blow up in your face as soon as you call `result.get()` and you have not enclosed it within an try-except-block.

The obvious 'pro' of an `error_callback` is the omitted try-except-block, the 'pro' of the regular callback also is reduced code length. Use both only for immediately returning tasks like checking and logging, to prevent blocking the thread your pool runs in.